# Configure API Gateway to delete item in dynamo db with composite key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

My goal is to delete an item in dynamo db with its **composite key** (e.g., primary + sort key).

Here is a chunk of my lambda function:

```
const { userAddress, loanId } = event.pathParameters;

  const params = {
    TableName: "Loans",
    Key: {
      userAddress: userAddress, // primary key
      loanId: loanId, // sort key
    },
  };

  try {
    const data = await documentClient.delete(params).promise();
    responseBody = JSON.stringify(data);
    statusCode = 201;
  } catch (err) {
    responseBody = `Unable to delete product: ${err}`;
    statusCode = 403;
  }
```

And here is a snapshot of my API gateway. I'm not sure how I should set it up to take accept the composite key:

[API Gateway Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7zvH.png)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with DynamoDB. You need to decide how you're going to pass the variables to the function. I suggest you use query parameters instead of path parameters if you're unfamiliar with the HTTP URI scheme and/or API Gateway, as this doesn't require defining the parameters in API Gateway.

Comment: Your route does not have pathparameters `loanId` and `userAddress` but only `id`. What is this `id` supposed to represent? To be able to get `loanId` and `uerAddress` from your path, it will have to look somehow like `/users/{userAddress}/{loanId}`, but I don't know how much sense that would make with your datamodel and the other endpoints of your API ...